# customerError handling asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, exception

So basically I have an Custom Authorize attribute and at some point it throwns an exception. I want to catch the exception and display the message to the user.

this is the contoller

```
[HandleError]
public class TestController : BaseController
{
    [CustomAuthorize("someperm, someperm2")]
    public ActionResult GamblerUser()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

this is the code in FilterConfig

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

this is the code in global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

and the web.config

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="~/Shared/Error" mode="On">
</customErrors>
```

and finally the view itself

```
@model HandleErrorInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}

<h2>Sorry Error Occured</h2> <br />
<h2>@Model.Exception.Message</h2>
```

and this is the message I get whenever the exception occurs.

Runtime Error
Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

I know that I am missing something very basic but this thing is just giving me headache.
I've look at tons of examples I just cant get this thing working.

Comment: override OnException in your controller, can you hit a breakpoint there? Rendering the error doesn't look like it's the problem.

Comment: is the exception in the context the one you are expecting?

Comment: Ah nevermind it is in the error page... ViewBag.Title = "Error" is the problem.

Comment: I completely removed that statement but it still gives me the same error :/.

Comment: ooh. my bad. Thats it thanks man problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewBag is null. I would use a static title in the html or find a way around it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6604217/266804).