# Asp.Net MVC call method when every view is called

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have some ViewBag need to pass to every views when them are called.
For example:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   ViewBag.Importan1 = "A";
   ViewBag.Importan2 = "B";
   return View();
}

public ActionResult Detail()
{
   ViewBag.Importan1 = "A";
   ViewBag.Importan2 = "B";
   return View();
}
```

and I want to:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}

public ActionResult Detail()
{
   return View();
}
```

but the ViewBag Important1 and Important2 are called implicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you a `custom filter attribute`. You create it (here some good examples [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) and do all the work inside. Then you just have to apply the filter on your controller and it will affect all your action methods.

Comment: Can it set ViewBag data?

Comment: That's a good question. I've never used it myself but I saw some posts with that kind of code: `filterContext.Controller.ViewBag` to get the ViewBag in your filter.

Comment: Hi @user3426870: I will try to get the result :)

Comment: Well, I tried and that's okay! Make just sure that you use `System.Web.Mvc` for the filter you inherit ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602638/how-can-i-use-data-placed-into-a-viewbag-by-a-filter-in-my-error-cshtml-view)).

Answer (score 0):

You can write a super class for the controller defines Index and Detail as virtual (to be able to override them and add some extra functionality)  and set Important1 and Important2 in your base class as

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
public virtual ActionResult Index()
{
   ViewBag.Importan1 = "A";
   ViewBag.Importan2 = "B";
   return View();
}

public virtual ActionResult Detail()
{
   ViewBag.Importan1 = "A";
   ViewBag.Importan2 = "B";
   return View();
}


}
```

that is it, you have Index and Detail with your desired behavior in all of your controllers which is inherited from MyController from example

```
public class Controller1 : MyController
{
  public override ActionResult Index()
  { 
    var result = base.Index();
    //do some manipulation here
    return result;
  }
}
```

### Another Solution

You can write this controller (I didn't check that on my pc)

```
public class MyController : Controller
{

  protected override void OnActionExecuting(
    ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
     //write your custom code here
  }
}
```

then inherit your controller from MyController

### Another Solution

using filterActionAttribute and write your own filer action attribute

Comment: Hi @RezaRahmati: I think it's not the best way to do, how about if I have another View than Index and Detail?

Comment: Hi @RezaRahmati: I read an article said: ViewBag is need to bind to a View, when a View is processed, ViewBag is available, otherwise, it will throw Exception. If the second solution is on bind in view when processing?

Comment: @Justin Sorry I don't have VisualStudio to test here but also there is OnResultExecuting and I am sure viewbag is available there via filterContext.Controller.ViewBag

Comment: @Justin BTW via Action Filter Attribute you need to add that attribute on every Action and it is not set globally on all actions

Comment: Hi @RezaRahmati: I will try to find out the result. Thank you very much