# Anti forgery token is meant for user "" but the current user is "user" Google Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

I keep getting the error  Anti forgery token is meant for user "" but the current user is "user". This is only happening while using Google Chrome and happens randomly too.

I have seen the other Stackoverflow threads and have tried all of them but none work.

Here is What I have tried

1) Disabled Page Caching

2) AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressIdentityHeuristicChecks = true.

3) [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")] on the Login Action

This only happens with Google Chrome (Usually after 4th or 5th try of logging out/logging in), I have tried all browsers and this issue never pops up.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you told us what platform you're working on. "the login action" is basically meaningless.

Comment: Did the same and more, kept having the same problem, but what helped was this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19471680/1216242

Answer (score 0):

Although you have mentioned that you have disabled the Page Caching but ur browser might already have some cache in the store. Press Ctrl+F5 in your browser to force the response from the server to be loaded. Hopefully you will not get the error any longer :)