# MVC 4 provided anti-forgery token was meant for user "" but the current user is "user"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, antiforgerytoken

I've recently put Live a web application which was built using **MVC 4** and **Entity Framework 5**. The **MVC** application uses **Razor Views**.

I noticed using **Elmah** that when users are logging into the application, sometimes they are getting the following error

```
The provided anti-forgery token was meant for user "" but the current user is "user"
```

I've done a bit of research already on how to fix this issue, but nothing seems to work for me. Please see my **Login View** and corresponding **Controller Actions** below.

**Razor View**

```
@if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{

using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

     <div class="formEl_a">

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Login Information</legend>

            <div class="lbl_a">
                Email
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "inpt_a" })<br />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
            </div>

            <div class="lbl_a">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field sepH_b">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "inpt_a" })<br />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>


        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <br />
      <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="btn btn_d sepV_a" />
        </p>

}    
}
```

**Controller**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login()
{
     return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid && _accountService.Logon(model.Email, model.Password, true))
     {
          //Validate
     }
     else
     {
          // inform of failed login
      }

}
```

I thought this all looked OK, but still the error persists. Does any have any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I think it is already answered here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970102/anti-forgery-token-is-meant-for-user-but-the-current-user-is-username

Comment: Are-you check this answer ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970102/anti-forgery-token-is-meant-for-user-but-the-current-user-is-username

Comment: If AllowAnonymous is removed from Login Action,then Login Action won't be called ("As user has not yet logged in")

Comment: The solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47868435/2736742

Answer (score 21):

I believe this is occurring because the users are double-clicking the submit button on the form. At least that's EXACTLY the case on my site.

[Troubleshooting anti-forgery token problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767768/troubleshooting-anti-forgery-token-problems)

Comment: Same here. Excerpt from most popular answer on linked question: I just removed the validation attribute. My site is always SSL and I'm not overly concerned about the risk. I just need it to work right now. Another solution would be disabling the button with javascript.

Comment: @Jerther: Do NOT remove the validation attribute, especially not on login page: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2120/when-the-use-of-a-antiforgerytoken-is-not-required-needed

Answer (score 11):

The validation code that runs against an AntiForgeryToken also checks your logged in user credentials haven’t changed – these are also encrypted in the cookie.
This means that if you logged in or out in a popup or another browser tab, your form submission will fail with the following exception:

```
System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException (0x80004005):
The provided anti-forgery token was meant for user "", but the current user is "SomeOne".
```

You can turn this off by putting `AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressIdentityHeuristicChecks = true;` in `Application_Start` method inside `Global.asax` file.

When a AntiForgeryToken doesn’t validate your website will throw an Exception of type `System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException`. You can make this a little easier by at least giving the user a more informative page targeted at these exceptions by catching the HttpAntiForgeryException.

```
private void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

    if (ex is HttpAntiForgeryException)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Server.ClearError(); //make sure you log the exception first
        Response.Redirect("/error/antiforgery", true);
    }
}
```

More info:

[Anti forgery token is meant for user “” but the current user is “username”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970102/anti-forgery-token-is-meant-for-user-but-the-current-user-is-username)

[Html.AntiForgeryToken – Balancing Security with Usability](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2014/01/29/htmlantiforgerytoken-ndash-balancing-security-with-usability)

Comment: Are there any problems associated with setting `AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressIdentityHeuristicChecks` to true?

Comment: No there is no problem with this setting. if user credentials have changed this problem occurred.

Comment: I actually prefer this solution because it keeps the security checks in place and informs the user correctly, unfortunately it's difficult to stop a user double-clicking or pressing the browser back button to return to the login page or something.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when

- User logs in
- Then on the Home Page the User hits Back Button to go back to Login
- User logs in as a different User
- This gave the exception : The provided anti-forgery token was meant for user "" but the current user is "user"

I found this was happening only in IE and I fixed it by doing a couple of things

1. Disabled output caching for the login page, because in debug mode I found that hitting the back button did not generate a new request to the Login page
2. On the login page I added a check to see if the user is already authenticated, and if so logged out the user, and then redirected to the Login page again.

   ```
   [AllowAnonymous]
   [OutputCache(NoStore=true, Location=System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.None)]
   public ActionResult Login)
   {
       if (HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
       {
           WebSecurity.Logout();
           Session.Abandon();
           return RedirectToAction("Login");
       }

       return View();
   }
   ```