# CSRF on singlepage using Web Api 2 backend

Tags: c#, antiforgerytoken

I'm trying to implement CSRF using AntiForgeryToken from .Net Framework on a single page application. I've implemented some code inside my .csthml file and i've created an AuthorizeAttribute:

**Index.cshtml**

```
<script>

    @functions{
        public string GetAntiForgeryToken()
        {
            string cookieToken, formToken;
            System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
            return cookieToken + ":" + formToken;                
        }
    }

    $.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
        var xxx = '@GetAntiForgeryToken()';
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF", xxx);
    });

</script>
```

**ValidateHttpAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.cs**

```
public class ValidateHttpAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var headers = actionContext.Request.Headers;

        var headerToken = headers.Contains("X-CSRF") ? headers.GetValues("X-CSRF").FirstOrDefault() : null;

        if (headerToken == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var tokenValues = headerToken.Split(':');

        if (tokenValues.Length < 2)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            var cookieToken = tokenValues[0];
            var formToken = tokenValues[1];
            try
            {
                AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }           
        return base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
    }
}
```

**MyController.cs**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ValidateHttpAntiForgeryTokenAttribute]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
     ...
    }
```

Every time that ValidateHttpAntiForgeryTokenAttribute is called, i got the following error:

```
The provided anti-forgery token was meant for user "CMP\usr", but the current user is "dev@company.net"
```

I would like to know why it displays the username of computer instead the username that is logged on application and why the token isn't changing when call **GetAntiForgeryToken()** is executed.

Thank in advance.

Comment: [Microsoft has provided implementation for AntiForgery Token validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateantiforgerytokenattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: That Microsoft implementation is only for HTML Form requests. The question here is about validating an XHR request.

Answer (score 1):

As quick fix (if you don't care about username validation inside anti-CSRF logic) would be:

```
AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressIdentityHeuristicChecks = true
```

somewhere in AppStart logic (global.asax).

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: `AntiForgeryConfig` does not provide `SuppressIdentityHeuristicChecks` for me

Comment: This does not prevent the exception in the question, which occurs during validation because the token contains a username which is different from the current Identity. `SuppressIdentityHeuristicChecks` simply makes Username, Claim, or AdditionalData required (https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/6248bfd24c/src/System.Web.WebPages/Helpers/AntiXsrf/TokenValidator.cs#L65), and throws an exception during token generation. Without it the username (if available) will still be set on the "form" token when generated, and validated on next request.

Comment: See updates to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15615786